# JavaScript - Concatenating a String to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I need a dollar sign before the numbers in all the input boxes.

e.g.: $0.00

[Here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/HeejulLee/7cpnn073/) When I put `("$" + Number(DollarValue).toFixed(2))`, `tTotal` and `gTotal` returns NaN.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  There's nearly 200 lines of javascript in there - which section in particular are you trying to do this in?

Comment: is it really necessary to use 200 lines of code to create a minimal representation of this issue? Pleaase include relevant code in the question itself

Comment: Most likely you `DollarValue` that is not a number `parseFloat()` if it is still NaN then check to see it could be something else than a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that `tTotal` and `gTotal` expect to take a value parseable as a number, but are being given `$123` instead. You could update the function to replace the `$` before calling the function, or inside the functions, before accessing the value...

```
str = "$123";
// replace `$` at start of string with nothing, then convert to number...
num = Number(str.replace(/^\$/,''));
// num -> 123
```